# ReactJS redux subscribe statements

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is store.subscribe( () => {} ) the only way to watch for changes in the Redux stores?

I fetch my users asynchronously and by the time the app is loaded the Users store is most likely empty so I have to do something like this:

```
store.subscribe( () => {

        var users = store.getState().users;
        if( users.length > 0 ) {
          this.setState({ ... })
        }

      });
```

Now I have 3 or 4 components I have to use the same logic in each of them. My question: is there a more elegant solution to this problem? Some way to listen to the changes in Redux on a 'global level'?

Comment: Have you read the react-redux documentation?

Comment: Usually you only subscribe to store changes on top level containers and pass them down to components through props. You should only re-subscribe in a child component if you find passing many props is too unweildly.  https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two answers here.

Yes, `store.subscribe()` is the only way to watch the store for changes (with the nitpicking exception that the store also implements `Symbol.observable`, so you if you're using observables you could also subscribe that way).

However, the `connect` function from the official React-Redux already handles the process of store subscriptions and extracting data that your components need.  Don't write store subscription logic yourself - use `connect`.  (I wrote a long comment on Reddit [explaining why you should use React-Redux instead of manually subscribing](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6hperk/i_use_react_and_redux_but_never_reactredux_what/dj0fywb/) .)